# Carregar arquivo e usá-lo para exportar dados

Tags: javascript, node.js, export

Eu tenho um arquivo chamado `preload.js`, ele é o primeiro a ser carregado. Eu preciso fazer uma verificação e enviar o resultado para vários arquivos quando solicitado. Eu tentei:

```js
module.exports = {
  online: false,
  client: client,
  async _load() {
    // ...
    this.online = true
    // ...
  }
}
```

mas sempre que um outro arquivo chama ele, parece que ele reseta e o `online` volta a ser `false`

tem algum jeito de eu fazer isso dar certo? ps. esse arquivo tem que ser:
1ª chamada: carregamento do arquivo
2ª ou mais chamadas: utilização dos dados carregados

Comment: quando a função _load() é chamada?
se ela não for invocada, o valor de online será false mesmo.

Comment: @WilliamBrunoRochaMoraes Então, ela é chamada quando eu inicio, eu quero que ela rode os resultados e que eles fiquem disponíveis das próximas vezes q eu usar eles

Comment: Você pode colocar colocar esses dados no .env ou então pode fazer uma classe, primeiro setar, depois só da os gets